How do I cancel asyncio coroutines on pressing the button again?
How could I cancel tasks that are already running when I click the button again?
The code I've sketched out, but it certainly doesn't work
class TasksManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = False
        self.list = [self.task_1, self.task_2, self.task_3]
 
    async def task_1(self):
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print("Task 1: ", i)
    
    async def task_2(self):
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print("Task 2: ", i)
 
    async def task_3(self):
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print("Task 3: ", i)
 
    async def click(self, e: ft.TapEvent):
        if not self.state:
            self.state = True
            list = [asyncio.create_task(task()) for task in self.list]
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(list, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            print(done, pending)
        else:
            # здесь нужно отменить корутины
            for task in pending:
                task.cancel()
 
def main(page: ft.Page):
    manager = TasksManager()
    button = ft.TextButton("Click", on_click=manager.click)
    page.add(button)
    page.update()
 
ft.app(main)

Tasks must be forcibly stopped

Can you provide more details? What do you mean by clicking the button "again"? What happens the first time? What do you expect to happen on the second time? What do you mean by "it certainly doesn't work"? How is it not working?

While more details would be helpful, there are several issues in click. However, I'm not familiar with Flet.

When you create a task, you need to save it off. This is mentioned in Python's documentation for asyncio.create_task:

Important: Save a reference to the result of this function, to avoid a task disappearing mid-execution. The event loop only keeps weak references to tasks. A task that isn’t referenced elsewhere may get garbage collected at any time, even before it’s done. For reliable “fire-and-forget” background tasks, gather them in a collection:


You are calling asyncio.wait, which will block until the tasks are complete or canceled. This is where more details about Flet and the use case are important. Is click launched in its own task? If not, two calls to click will wait for the first one to complete before the second one is executed.

You are not saving the tasks inside the class, so there is no way for subsequent calls to click to cancel the tasks created in prior executions.



Try something like this:
class TaskManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = False
        self.__tasks_to_create = [self.task_1, self.task_2, self.task_3]
        self.__tasks: list[asyncio.Task] = []
 
    ...
 
    async def click(self, e: ft.TapEvent):
        if not self.state:
            self.state = True
            self.__tasks = [asyncio.create_task(task()) for task in self.__tasks_to_create]

    async def cancel_tasks(self, e: ft.TapEvent):
        for task in self.__tasks:
            task.cancel()

        self.__tasks = []
 
def main(page: ft.Page):
    manager = TaskManager()
    button = ft.TextButton("Click", on_click=manager.click)
    cancel_button = ft.TextButton("Cancel", on_click=manager.cancel_tasks)
    page.add(button)
    page.add(cancel_button)
    page.update()
 
ft.app(main)


This  solution suffers from one of the problems you mentioned. The task is cancelled, but then it is not given a chance to execute its cancellation on the event loop. Instead it is immediately discarded. This is important as any context managers or finally blocks in the task may not get an opportunity to tidy up before the task is garbage collected.

That's a good point and potentially true because of the line self.__tasks = []. In real code, one should use the other task related functions to wait on the tasks to be canceled, such as the Task.cancelled method, before clearing out the task references. But that code is a bit dirty since you'd want to have timeouts and such, so I'll leave the answer as is.

In the instance of flet, which dispatches each UI event in its own task, I think the right think to do is to await the tasks in the click function. That way each task is guaranteed to be run to completion (or cancellation). As each UI event is its own task, you can be assured that you are not blocking other UI events from being handled. You'd still keep the tasks list so that they can be cancelled when requested.
